# IF ELSE Condition in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, db-browser-sqlite

I am new to SQLite.

I am looking for `IF ELSE` in SQLite to perform `UPDATE` OR `INSERT` operation based on the condition check.

What I tried is:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TblTest WHERE ID = 1 AND Name = 'XYZ')
BEGIN
END
    UPDATE TblTest
    SET Address = 'NYC',
    Mobile='102938340'
    WHERE ID = 1 AND Name='XYZ'
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TblTest(ID,Name,Address,Mobile)
    VALUES(1,'XYZ','NYC','102938340');
END
```

Getting an error:

> Result: near "IF": syntax error

Comment: And what problem you are facing here?

Comment: Getting an error `Result: near "IF": syntax error`.

Comment: What is the significance of the check on `ID = 1`?

Comment: That's not valid sqlite syntax. See https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html for the SQL dialect it understands.

Comment: I *think* you're looking for what's known as [UPSERT](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ID` and `Name` are not a unique combination for your table and so you can't use `INSERT OR REPLACE`, you can execute these statements:

```
UPDATE TblTest
SET Address = 'NYC',
    Mobile='102938340'
WHERE ID = 1 AND Name='XYZ';

INSERT INTO TblTest(ID,Name,Address,Mobile)
SELECT 1,'XYZ','NYC','102938340'
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TblTest WHERE ID = 1 AND Name = 'XYZ');
```

If there is no row in the table with `ID = 1 AND Name = 'XYZ'` then the `UPDATE` statement will not update anything because the condition in the `WHERE` clause will return nothing. But the `INSERT` statement will insert the new row.
If there is a row with `ID = 1 AND Name = 'XYZ'` then the `UPDATE` statement will update it and the `INSERT` statement will not insert anything because `NOT EXISTS` will return `FALSE`.

Comment: Clever answer, but note that this should be run inside a transaction to ensure that the update and insert occur together atomically.

Answer (score 1):

If you had a unique index on `(ID, Name)`, you could take advantage of SQLite's `REPLACE` syntax:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx_id_name ON TblTest (ID, Name);

INSERT OR REPLACE INTO TblTest (ID, Name, Address, Mobile)
VALUES
    (1, 'XYZ', 'NYC', '102938340');
```

This would have the effect that if a record with `ID=1` and `Name=XYZ` exist in the table already, an update would be performed.  Otherwise, a new record would be inserted.

The unique index on both `ID` (presumably the current primary key) *and* `Name` might seem redundant.  However, this combination should ideally always be unique anyway.